# Number of Occurences

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to Python and trying to use it for competitive programming.

This is the question:
You are given an unsorted array of characters 'n' and a character 'x'. You have to find the number of times x occurs in character array
Input format:
First line contains an integer T, number of test cases. Then follows T test cases. Each test case consists of two lines. First line contains N, length of the array. Second lines contains N space separated characters. Example
Input
2
4
a b c d
5
a b x c d

Output
0
1
In c++ I know we start like this:

```
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--)
{
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  int arr[n];
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    cin>>arr[i];
  }
 ...
```

How do we do the same in python?
This is my code:

```
t = int(input())

while t:
   n = int(input())
   arr = [x for x in raw_input().split()]

   res = 0
   for i in arr:
     if i == 'x':
     res += 1
   t -=1
print(res)
```

Getting runtime error for this

I think the issue is with how I'm taking inputs to run test cases but not sure

Comment: `raw_input` doesn't exist in Python 3, but question is tagged `python-3.x`.

Comment: "I'm getting a runtime error" *what error are you getting exactly?*

Comment: In any case, I don't understand the point of your while loop. This could just be implemented as `input(); print(input().count('x'))`. That's it, that's all you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@juanpa arrivillaga answered your question, but it may help you understand that answer better to see an actual implementation.

Example:

```
from io import StringIO
io_buffer = """2
4
abcd
5
abxcd
"""
with StringIO(io_buffer) as buffer:
    num_test_cases = int(buffer.readline())

    for _ in range(num_test_cases):
        
        num_chars = int(buffer.readline())

        char_line = buffer.readline().strip()
        
        # This is the important part - everything else is overhead
        x_count = char_line.count("x")
        
        print(f"character string: {char_line:>5}, length: {num_chars}, x count: {x_count}")
```

Output:

```
character string:  abcd, length: 4, x count: 0
character string: abxcd, length: 5, x count: 1
```